# Symfony2 Logout code placement, where do I put the invalidate code

Tags: php, symfony

New Symfony user here...

The examples in the Symfony Documentation don't actually have any examples of how to do a proper logout. Here is my security.yml

```
security:
    encoders: 
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER]
    providers:
        chain_provider: 
            chain:
                providers: [in_memory, user_db]
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users: 
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        user_db:
            entity: { class: AppBundle:User, property: username }
    firewalls:
        main: 
            pattern: /.*
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                default_target_path: /
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
                invalidate_session:   true
                delete_cookies:
                    name:
                    path: null
                    domain: null
            security: true
            anonymous: true
    access_control:
        - { path: /login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /cms/user, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: /.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I was under the impression with those settings that simply hitting the /logout route the session would be destroyed and the user would be redirected to the login page. However in trying to do this, I get a no route found error.

I found this code here on stack-overflow...

```
$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);
$this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
```

Great, but I'm so new in Symfony that I don't know where to put it. All of the examples here on Stack give that code, but don't say how to implement it. Do I write a logout action like this?

```
    /**
     * @Route("/logout")
     */
    public function logoutAction() {
        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);
        $this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();

        //if this works how do I redirect to another route, 
        //specifically back to /login
        return $this->render(
            //do i need a template?
            //do i need the array here?
            );
    }
```

Comment: No route means no route, so add route with /logout path, so simple.

Comment: OK so I added this.../**
     * @Route("/logout")
     */
    public function logoutAction() {
        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken(null);
        $this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
    } And it worked. I wonder why this is not in the documentation. PLease put this in an answer so I can give you checkmark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No needed to write logout action in controller. All you have to do, is add the route with logout path.
In `app/config/routing.yml`:

```
user_logout:
    path: /logout
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed